# How to read/parse the response of a stripe api request

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, rest, stripe-payments

I have combed thru this site and many others and cannot seem to figure out what my issue is. Please excuse my ignorance, I've never worked with API's at all.

So, I have a proprietary in-house CRM system built in .NET, WinForms. We are adding the functionality for auto-pay, and decided to use Stripe. We are calling Create Customer in Stripe when we create a new customer in our application.

I was able to add the customer succesfully, with the following code:

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "redacted"
        Dim options = New CustomerCreateOptions With {
                .Name = CustomerName(),
                .Email = CustomerEmail(),
                .Phone = PrimaryPhone(),
                .TaxExempt = "exempt"}

            Dim service = New CustomerService()
        service.Create(options)
```

This works fine. What I'm having trouble with is how do I access their response, so I can pull the stripe customer id to attach to my customer in my database after they've been added to stripe.

Example Response

```
{
  "id": "cus_123456",
  "object": "customer",
  "address": null,
  "balance": 0,
  "created": 1660188438,
  "currency": "usd",
  "default_source": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": "My First Test Customer (created for API docs at https://www.stripe.com/docs/api)",
  "discount": null,
  "email": null,
  "invoice_prefix": "26B1AAE",
  "invoice_settings": {
    "custom_fields": null,
    "default_payment_method": null,
    "footer": null,
    "rendering_options": null
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "name": null,
  "next_invoice_sequence": 1,
  "phone": null,
  "preferred_locales": [],
  "shipping": null,
  "tax_exempt": "none",
  "test_clock": null
}
```

I want to read the customer id from their response.

TLDR How do I read a response from Stripe API?

Answer (score 2):

Every API requests you make with Stripe's API will return an object. You have to store the response in a variable if you want to access it.

If we take your example you want this

```
Dim service = New CustomerService()
Dim customer = service.Create(options)
```

With that the `customer` variable is now an instance of the `Customer` [class](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities/Customers/Customer.cs) in the library with all the properties you care about such as `Id`, `Email` or `Address`.

Stripe covers this in details with their quickstart tutorial for each language [here](https://stripe.com/docs/development/quickstart/dotnet).